# Where does `xargs` add the option from STDIN?

Tags: xargs

Due to some reasons, the option order is important to the command. For example, different options order may cause different actions in `ffmpeg`, so where does `xargs` add the option from `stdin`?

For example:

```
$ echo 'output.avi' | xargs ffmpeg -i input.avi -r 24
```

is totally equivalent to:

```
$ ffmpeg -i inpit.avi -r 24 output.avi
```

but if I want to send `input.avi` from `echo` to `xargs ffmpeg -i -r 24 output.avi` by pipe, how do I set the string from STDIN to a specified position?

Comment: Please give an example of the command you're running.

Comment: There is no example (so far). I'm just curious how `xargs` perform.

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure where STDIN comes in. Anyway, `xargs` puts the arguments exactly where you tell it to. It would be easier to understand what you're asking if you could give an example where you think the arguments could be added in different places.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow you but if you're asking how you can control where `xargs` places the arguments when passed to it, you can use the switch `-I{}` to denote what macro you want to use for input that's pasted to `xargs` and then make use of this macro where ever you want to have the things passed to `xargs` expanded.

**NOTE:** I'm using the notation `{}` for my macro I then simply put that macro 
where ever I want the arguments expanded.

#### Example

```
$ echo hi | xargs -I{} echo {}
hi

$ echo hi | xargs -I{} echo {} {}
hi hi

$ echo hi | xargs -I{} echo {} {} bye
hi hi bye
```

*excerpt from xargs man page*

```
   -I replace-str
      Replace  occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with 
      names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not 
      terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline 
      character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```